# Github multiple Fine grained access token

Tags: git, github, github-fine-grained-tokens

My question is quite basic, so I was surprised not to find an answer online.

I just created an organization on GitHub and discovered that my personal fine-grained access token does not grant me access to the organization's repositories.

I'm also unable to create a token that provides access to both my personal repositories and the organization's.

I've also encountered an issue with storing two tokens in the Git default credentials helper (I tried setting both in the ~/.git-credentials file, but Git seems to only use the first line).

Comment: To store different tokens for different Github accounts: [`git config --global credential.useHttpPath true`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-credentialuseHttpPath). Or [`credential.https://github.com.useHttpPath`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-credentiallturlgt) to make the change only for Github.